# How to execute scala swing application?

Tags: swing, scala

i am new for scala .and trying to execute swing application.
I am using scala 2.8
I have compiled the program successfully but..
while executing it is showing the error like no such file..
can any 1 please help me out?

i m providing the code i am trying to execute.

```
Gui.scala

import swing._

object Gui extends SimpleSwingApplication

{
    def top=new MainFrame {
        title="swing"
        val b1=new Button{
            text = "ok"
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
scalac Gui.scala
```

it compiles successfully and create class file
but when I try

```
scala Gui
```

it just replies

> No such File

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace?

Comment: The above example runs with Scala nightly. Are you sure the compilation was successful? Try removing the empty line between `object` and `{`.

Comment: After you compile it, shouldn't you run it with the JVM instead of the Scala compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 5C88-8D6C

 Directory of D:\src\scala_ex\ex1

01.12.2010  09:25    <DIR>          .
01.12.2010  09:25    <DIR>          ..
01.12.2010  09:24               173 gui.scala
               1 File(s)            173 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  24 575 205 376 bytes free

D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>more gui.scala
import swing._

object Gui extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "swing"
    val b1 = new Button{
      text = "ok"
    }
  }
}

D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.8.1.final -- Copyright 2002-2010, LAMP/EPFL
```

Compile:

```
D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>scalac gui.scala

D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 5C88-8D6C

 Directory of D:\src\scala_ex\ex1

01.12.2010  09:26    <DIR>          .
01.12.2010  09:26    <DIR>          ..
01.12.2010  09:26               485 Gui$$anon$1$$anon$2.class
01.12.2010  09:26               557 Gui$$anon$1.class
01.12.2010  09:26               558 Gui$.class
01.12.2010  09:26             1 467 Gui.class
01.12.2010  09:24               173 gui.scala
               5 File(s)          3 240 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  24 575 201 280 bytes free
```

Execute:

```
D:\src\scala_ex\ex1>scala -cp . Gui
```

And the applications starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct cut&paste from the Scala code, as the blank line between `object Gui` and `{` causes a compilation error.

Now, if you fix that error and compile this with Scala 2.8, you should get these classes in the local directory:

- Gui$$anon$1$$anon$2.class
- Gui$$anon$1.class
- Gui$.class
- Gui.class

If you don't, then either the compilation did not work, or there's something else missing. For example, if you declared a `package X` at the top (and removed it from the example), then `Gui` won't be in the local directory, but under a subdirectory X, and you should invoke it by typing `scala X.Gui`.

Another possibility is that you have some Java environment variable pointing the output directory to someplace else.

Comment: the prob was due to java environment variables